# "No X11 DISPLAY variable was set [...]" when using java.swing

Tags: linux, environment-variables, java, display

When I'm trying to run a Java GUI application from the command line, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException:
"No X11 DISPLAY variable was set,
or no headful library support was found,
but this program performed an operation which requires it,"
```

I keep getting this error whenever I try to run code with `java.swing` GUI components.

`$DISPLAY` is set to `:0` and `java --version` gives me `openjdk 19.0.1`.

edit:
I tried to run java Main with either wayland or xorg but I get the same error.

Comment: How do you start the binary? Is there some scripting or user-switching involved?

Comment: Sorry in advance, Im a linux beginner. To run the applicaton I compile with "javac" and run with "java". I hope this is what you meant.

Comment: So must importantly: Is an X-server installed? What kind of Linux do you use? You probably have only wayland?

Comment: Welcome to the site. When asked for clarifications, please don't respond in comments, but edit your post to include the requested information. Reading through the comments is rather painful, and comments are subject to removal without notice by moderators.

Comment: I am also experiencing this as well when using Worldographer that I packaged in a Flatpak. When I switch to GNOME (Xorg) it works, but GNOME (wayland) I get this error above. https://github.com/FilBot3/com.inkwellideas.Worldographer

Answer (score 0):

Rolling back to openjdk-17 worked for me, you might be able to get away with a more recent version. Openjdk 19 starts in headless by default, so therefore no display.